# web scraping convert unix timestamp to date format

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to webscrape a flight data website using beautifulsoup in python but the timestamp is in unix timestamp how can i convert to regular datetime format. There are several such columns to be converted.

```html
#scheduled_departure 
result_items[0]['flight']['time']['scheduled']['departure']
```

and the output is shown as ***1655781000***. how can I convert it to ***Tue, Jun 21, 2022 8:40 AM***

Answer (score 0):

```
import time


print(time.strftime("%a, %b %d, %Y %H:%M %p", time.localtime(1655781000)))
```

Comment: Please include an explanation with your answer to help readers understand how this works, and solves the problem. You can click the edit button at the bottom of your answer to add an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one Unix time and it is created by using the UTC/GMT time zone. This means you might have convert time zones to calculate timestamps.

```
import datetime
from pytz import timezone

local_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1655781000)
local_time_str = datetime.datetime.strftime(local_datetime, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %p")
print(f'Local time: {local_time_str}')

other_timezone = 'Asia/Kolkata'  # Replace your interest timezone here
remote_datetime = local_datetime.astimezone(timezone(other_timezone))
remote_time_str = datetime.datetime.strftime(remote_datetime, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %p")
print(f'Time at {other_timezone }: {remote_time_str}')
```